# Компиляция приложения на ionic в ios

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic

Разрабатываю кроссплатформенное приложение. Создал всё приложение на windows под android. Приложение для android выглядит одинаково в браузере и на реальном устройстве. Проблема возникла после попытки скомпилировать приложение на ios. Использую MacBook и его терминал, а так же xcode. Проводил тесты в браузере - приложение выглядит хорошо. Запускаю на устройстве или эмуляторе через xcode - получаю съехавшую вёрстку и непонятно откуда появившиеся чёрные отступу сверху и снизу на экране. Как ни пытаюсь что-то исправить - ничего не выходит. Разве ionic это не инструмент для быстрого создания КРОССПЛАТФОРМЕННЫХ приложений? Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 0):

1) ионик это действительно инструмент для создания КРОССПЛАТФОРМЕННЫХ приложений.

2) нет, никто с таким не сталкивался.

вроде все ответил